# Executar laradock (laravel e Docker) com mysql local

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, docker

Eu tinha meu ambiente Laravel funcionando no XAMPP. Porém, dadas algumas necessidades, precisei mudar para o Docker. Para isso, comecei a usar o Laradock. No entanto, eu quero rodar somente o php e apache no docker e não o banco de dados, pois quero usar o banco de dados antigo (do XAMPP).

Portanto, eu tenho um container do laravel rodando no meu computador, até aí tudo bem, mas quando tento entrar no site pelo navegador, encontro o seguinte erro:

[image: logo do erro]

Eu imagino que a razão desse erro seja que o container não consegue acessar o mysql rodando na minha maquina na porta 3306, porque as credenciais no .env do projeto estão corretas. Mas acho que estou errado nisso. Enfim, alguém pode me ajudar?

Eu consigo usar o banco de dados instalado na minha máquina ou vou ter que criar um novo com o comando `docker-compose up -d mysql`?

Comment: Encontrei nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/24326540#24326540). É necessário alterar o valor da variável DB_HOST no arquivo .env do seu projeto. Então eu troquei de "127.0.0.1" para "host.docker.internal"

Answer (score 1):

Se você está usando docker-compose, você pode também usar a rede do host como rede do docker, o que possibilita que seus containers dentro do compose possam acessar aplicações do host. Mais [aqui](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode).

Se estiver executando comandos docker puro (do tipo docker run, build etc), pode passar a flag "--network=host" que terá o mesmo efeito acima.

Espero ter ajudado.